# How to sort guava multimap? (KEY=DATE)

Tags: java, sorting, guava, multimap

I have a

```
Multimap<Date,Invoice> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

from guava. I was wondering how to SORT the the Date key in the multimap.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
        Iterator<Date> dateItr = multimap.keySet().iterator();
        Set<Date> treeSet = new TreeSet<Date>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

and later I loop through the treeSet iterator. Any idea how to avoid this circumvention?

Comment: [TreeMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Guava team member here.

Use `TreeMultimap`, or if you need to map into `List`s, use `MultimapBuilder`:

```
return MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()
```

Comment: I tried the your code but I can't figure it out how to construct it with my classes.

Comment: Can you please write the line of code that relates to KEY=Date and V=Invoice. Thanks!

Comment: Um.  Replace the letter `K` with `Date` and `V` with `Invoice`, and that'll work.

Comment: Post your revised code in the question, then, because you shouldn't get a compile error.

Comment: You're storing it in a `TreeMultimap` variable; of course that's not going to work.  Put it in a `ListMultimap` and it'll be fine.